Waypoint Optimization: Routes API vs Route Optimization API
I understand both Google Maps Routes API and the (newly-launched) Route Optimization API will return the best possible route through multiple stops.  Route Optimization API seems like it can handle more advanced scenarios and with higher limits on the number of waypoints.  But I'd just like to know how to use it to optimize a set of intermediate waypoints in the most efficient order, based on this example:
curl -X POST -H 'content-type: application/json' -d ' {
  "origin": {
    "address": "Adelaide,SA"
  },
  "destination": {
    "address": "Adelaide,SA"
  },
  "intermediates": [
    {"address": "Barossa+Valley,SA"},
    {"address": "Clare,SA"},
    {"address": "Connawarra,SA"},
    {"address": "McLaren+Vale,SA"}
  ],
  "travelMode": "DRIVE",
  "optimizeWaypointOrder": "true"
  }' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'X-Goog-Api-Key: YOUR_API_KEY' \
-H 'X-Goog-FieldMask: routes.optimizedIntermediateWaypointIndex' \
'https://routes.googleapis.com/directions/v2:computeRoutes'

Routes API would return the optimized order:
"optimizedIntermediateWaypointIndex": [
                3,
                2,
                0,
                1
            ]

What would the equivalent Route Optimization API OptimizeTours request look like (assuming a single trip)?
(I've reviewed how to construct a request message for OptimizeTours but not sure what properties to use.)

There are differences in the fields of a Waypoint in each API.  As for Route Optimization API a Waypoint provides an additional field for heading which allows you to set a direction of travel by entering a compass heading.  As requested, you could use arrivalLocation in lieu of arrivalWaypoint and/or departureLocation in lieu of departureWaypoint.  Not a big deal, but worth noting

The Route Optimization API provides an example that does just that.
AFAIR, it's more complicated than just using an API key and CURL, but the website describes how to try it. As for the request JSON itself, something like this should work (I translated your addresses to latitude/longitude):
{
  "model": {
    "globalStartTime": "2024-01-01T00:00:00",
    "globalEndTime": "2024-01-01T23:59:59",
    "vehicles": [
      {
        "startLocation": {
          "latitude": -34.9285,
          "longitude": 138.6007
        },
        "endLocation": {
          "latitude": -34.9285,
          "longitude": 138.6007
        },
        "costPerHour": 20.0
      }
    ],
    "shipments": [
      {
        "pickups": [
          {
            "arrivalLocation": {
              "latitude": -34.6182,
              "longitude": 138.9001
            },
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "pickups": [
          {
            "arrivalLocation": {
              "latitude": -33.8359,
              "longitude": 138.6142
            },
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "pickups": [
          {
            "arrivalLocation": {
              "latitude": -37.2916,
              "longitude": 140.8336
            },
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "pickups": [
          {
            "arrivalLocation": {
              "latitude": -35.2192,
              "longitude": 138.5448
            },
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

API keys can be used as @Avnish has, but only if the user or a service account is authenticated to the GCP project where the API key was created, using the gcloud CLI.  The question was worded specifically as a series of waypoints, of which Waypoint is a type of object with unique fields in each API.  In Route Optimization API Waypoint you have the option of giving a compass heading for the vehicle, but since the original request does not specify a direction/heading, you have correctly chosen arrivalLocation in lieu of arrivalWaypoint in your Shipment VisitRequest objects
